# Confused about parameters in Haskell lambdas

Tags: haskell

I've been learning Haskell recently and came across something I don't quite understand: the parameters of a lambda function.

In the *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good* book, chap. 5, there are the following two functions:

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem' y ys = foldr (\x acc -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys
```

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) []
```

In the first function, the accumulator is listed as the lambda's second parameter, but then is the first to follow the lambda for `foldl`, which I took to mean it would be the *first*, not the second, thus, defying expectations.

Whereas, in the second function, it follows expectations, showing up as the lambda's first parameter, making the list that `reverse'` takes as a parameter the second for the lambda.

I tested both functions and they work as expected. I also noticed that one function involves a right fold and the other a left fold, but I'm not sure why that would alter the meaning of the parameters.

QUESTION: Can someone explain what I'm missing? Why are the parameters seeming to swap places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`foldl` and `foldr` expect the accumulating function to have different formats. The two functions have the following types:

```hs
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

You're correct that in `foldr`, the accumulator is the second argument, and in `foldl` it's the left.

---

While this may seem unintuitive, it may help to think of `foldl` and `foldr` in terms of how they associate values in a list, the following images come from the ["fold" page on the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold):

[image]
[image]

Treating the natural order of the list as left to right: In `foldr`, the accumulator starts at the right hand side of the list, so it's natural that it's the second argument, while in foldl, the opposite is true.

Comment: Makes sense. I also learned I need to scrutinize the function signature in the future. Thanks.

Comment: hoogle (https://hoogle.haskell.org) is a great resource for quickly investigating type signatures, (as is `:t` in ghci)

Answer (score 3):

It is just a convention that the accumulator in `foldr` is the second argument, and in `foldl` it is the first argument.

Why was this convention chosen?

1. The first reason was answered by @Joe. `acc` is the folded part of the list. In `foldl` it's left part but in `foldr` it's right part. So it's natural to provide `acc` as left operand (the first argument) to folding operator in `foldl` and as right operand (the second argument) to folding operator in `foldr`.
2. `foldl` should iterate over all the elements in the provided list, while `foldr` should not. You can provide folding operator to the `foldr` which can skip rest of elements in the list. The first example does that. The second argument `acc` in the `foldr` is thing which is not computed yet, it hold folding the rest of elements. And if you skip it in your folding operator it never be computed. In your example, if `x == y` you just "return" `True` (and skip rest elements), else you "return" `acc` which force to evaluate the next element in the list. So, `foldr` works lazyly, but `foldl` works strictly.
3. In Haskell is another convention. When operator can works lazyly then it usually have the first argument with strict semantic and the second with non strict. For example: `&&`, `||` are this sort of operators.

   ```
   False && undefined => False
   True || undefined => True
   ```

   Folding operator in your the first example is lazy too.

   ```
   (\x acc -> if x == y then True else acc) y undefined => True
   ```

   And it can be rewrite in terms of `||` like this:

   ```
   (\x acc -> x == y || acc)
   ```

Combining above reasons together we have what we have :-)

Comment: I wouldn't really say it's a convention. It is an unarguable part of the definitions of foldl and foldr. Unlike, say, the convention of naming a list variable `xs`, you can't go against it if you disagree: you will get a type error, because that is how the functions are defined to work. You may argue that it was a convention to *define* foldl and foldr in this way, But if this is the case you are making, you should say so.

Comment: The lazy evaluation justification makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: @amalloy I wouldn't really say it's an unarguable part of the definitions. You can rewrtite `foldr` which will be have the type like `foldl` (or wise versa). I agree that it was convention to define foldl and foldr in this way. But I think on which kind of level was convention is not matter for answer on this question.

Comment: `foldl` is *not* strict, contrary to what you might expect. For a strict left fold, you need `foldl'` (note the trailing prime/apostrophe). This is a common pitfall.

Comment: @freestyle You could rewrite them as you describe, but then they would not be foldr and foldl. They would be very similar functions, but different, defined differently, and incompatible.

Comment: @jlwoodwa Yes, you are right! I try to say that it is strict on provided list (not content of elements). It should deconstruct all list. That mean if somewhere tail is bottom then result will be bottom (not metter what folding operator was provided).

Comment: @amalloy It's very strange conclusion.